# toggle visibility of chain group in constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, visibility, android-constraintlayout

In previous xml layout, I have multiple view groups with few elements inside. Hide each view group will also hide all of its child elements. Since I wanted to have flat structure and tried **ConstraintLayout**. Cool I know how to chain element with spread to align properly. Since flat structure does not have wrapped **LinearLayout**, now i have 3 views to hide instead. I would like to know if there is alternative to achieve this.

**Without constraint layout**

```
<RelativeLayout....
..........
..........
<LinearLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/filter_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTerminal"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            style="@style/PurpleSubtitle"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lblTerminal"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/lblCategory"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            style="@style/PurpleSubtitle"
            android:text="@string/lblCategory"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
  .......
  .......
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**With constraint layout**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    .....
    .....
    .....
       #happy that i no longer need LinearLayout for align properly
       <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTerminal"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            style="@style/PurpleSubtitle"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lblTerminal"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_search"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/view3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"/>

        <View
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_search"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/lblCategory"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/lblTerminal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/lblCategory"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/i_down_yellow"
            style="@style/PurpleSubtitle"
            android:text="@string/lblCategory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/view3" />



  ......
  ......
  ......

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to toggle visibility of whole constraint layout or child of it?

Comment: yes i want to toggle the visibility of chain group elements

Comment: So what is the problem when you are changing visibility.?

Comment: with linear layout view group, i can just hide viewgroup and all of its childs will b hidden. with constraints layout, i dont seem to have this power anymore. mean i have to hide each view

Comment: Constraints layout is also ViewGroup so you can hide whole layout instead of hide every child layout.

Comment: i also have other views in same layout file as well. i only show portions of it. i should have uploaded all . i will update my question soon

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, so now in **`ConstraintLayout`** also we can handle visibility of particular groups of Views using the **`Group`**

> This is a new feature introduced in ConstraintLayout which is currently in Beta version.

How to add beta `ConstraintLayout` to your project? Follow the steps below:

**Add maven support in project gradle file as below**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Then in app gradle dependencies add ConstraintLayout library dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

**Now you have to add a `Group` in your `ConstraintLayout` as follows**

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button7,button3,button2"
        android:id="@+id/group" />
```

**Where in `Group`, the reference id...**

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="button7,button3,button2"
```

... contains the **comma separated view id's you want to handle run time**, so, in an Activity, you just bind the `Group` as below and handle the visibility

```
import android.support.constraint.Group; //import statement in activity

Group group=(Group)findViewById(R.id.group); //bind view from xml
group.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //this will visible all views
group.setVisibility(View.GONE); //this will set Gone to all views
group.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //this will set INVISIBLE to all view
```

**EDIT: `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0 stable version was released on 12 April 2018** https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/constraintlayout-110.html

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

> Edit for Android X: If anyone is using the Android X package, you can find package
>   info here

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Is the `group` removed from `constraintLayout`? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: It is in the beta version follow steps for how to add beta version check this is new beta 3 release https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/constraintlayout-110-beta-3-is-now.html?m=1

Comment: I would like to add that currently changing Group visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` doesn't work. It looks like a bug in implementation.
More information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865436/cant-set-visibility-on-constraint-group

Answer (score 6):

If you are using beta version of constraintlayout, please follow @pavan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44470992/2949612)

If you are using AndroidX, Please follow below steps to integrate constraintlayout and Group:

**1)** Add AndroidX constraint layout dependancy in your project:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

**2)** Use ConstraintLayout Group as below in your project:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                    android:id="@+id/groupDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" // Default visibility for group views
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textViewUserName, ..." // id's which you want to include in group
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**3)** Here is the coding part for toggle visibility:

```
private lateinit var groupDetails:Group

...
groupDetails = findViewById(R.id.groupDetails)
groupDetails.visibility = View.GONE // Change visibility
```

Hope it's helps while using AndroidX.

Answer (score -6):

You can use that same Linear Layout as child of Constraint Layout too, OR you can also make all those 3 widgets as child of another Constraint Layout and make that layout as child of main Constraint Layout.

Then you can maintain the visibility and other stuff same as before.

Comment: hmm i want to have flat structure, seem like i have to use view group as u mentioned :-(

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it thought both Constraint Layout OR Linear Layout.

Comment: yeah @lelloman, If i wrap with LinearLayout, no point using ConstraintLayout